# Creating Instances of the structure twice

Tags: android, class, structure

I have this code:

```
Tile tile[] = new Tile [40];
for(int i; i<40; i++) tile[id]= new Tile();
```

If I need to make it again in the cod, what will happen?
Will the old structure be overwritten?
Is it a good thing to do or not?

Comment: you mean run the for loop again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If I need to make it again in the cod, what will happen? Will the old structure be overwritten?
```

Yes completely, all of the old structure of data that was added in your `tile` array will be overwritten when new data when you run the `for-loop` the second time.

```
Is it a good thing to do or not?
```

If you are still using some old data in your `tile` array then it will be replaced with the new data thus giving you unexpected result.

On the other hand if you are not using some of the old data and you want all of then to be normalized to a new state then running the loop again is required.